# Google results link my site to a spammy Michael Kors site

Tags: seo, google-search

I tried using Google Webmaster tools to re-crawl the site and it hasn't helped.

Does anyone know why the link on Google might say 'halalgems.com', but redirect to another site?

The description is also incorrect.

[image: What happens when you search for 'halal gems' on Google!]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears as though your website has been hacked, and not a problem with Google.

After looking at the response from your website once someone goes to it from that google page, it is your website that does the redirecting.

I cannot determine the source of this issue, as that would likely require access to your server. Good luck with tracking it down!
[image]